# How to use join properply in codeigniter with multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

Im trying to connect 5 tables in codeigniter and i am having some trouble getting the correct result please help. I think the error is in my query but Im not sure.

I've tried many join statements already but I cant seem to find the correct answer. That's why I posted it here because im hopeless alreadyyy please help someoneee ~

Here are the schema and DB. Hope this helps

**Schema**

[image]

**Database**

[image]

```
 public function get_receiving_details_mawb($id){

        $this->ops_db->select('d.quantity, e.sku_code, a.quantity AS actual, 
        abs(d.quantity - a.quantity) AS variance');
        $this->ops_db->from('sk_rcv_d a');
        $this->ops_db->where_in('a.rcv_id', $id);
        $this->ops_db->join('sk_rcv_h b', 'a.rcv_id = b.id', 'inner');
        $this->ops_db->join('sk_booking_h c', 'b.booking_id = c.id','inner');
        $this->ops_db->join('sk_booking_d d', 'c.id = d.book_id', 'inner');
        $this->ops_db->join('sk_item e', 'd.item_id = e.id', 'inner');
        $this->ops_db->group_by('d.id');//d.id
        $query = $this->ops_db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_rcvh_mawb($id) {

       $this->ops_db->where("mawb_no", $id);
       $query = $this->ops_db->get("sk_rcv_h");
       $how = array();
       foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
         $id = $row['id'];
         $how[] = $id;
       }
       return $how; 
    }

-------------------------------
        $wat  = $this->wh_db->get_rcvh_mawb($mawb);
        $item_details = array();
        $items = array();
        $results  = $this->wh_db->get_receiving_details_mawb($wat);
        foreach($results as $res) {
          extract($res);
          if (! array_key_exists($sku_code, $items)) {
          $items[$sku_code] = array("sku_code" => $sku_code, "quantity" => 0, 
          "actual" => 0, "variance" => 0);
         }
         $items[$sku_code]['quantity'] = $quantity;
         $items[$sku_code]['actual'] += $actual;
         $items[$sku_code]['variance'] = $items[$sku_code]['quantity'] - 
         $items[$sku_code]['actual']; 
        }

        foreach($items as $res) {
        $item_details[] = array("sku" => $res['sku_code'], "qty" => 
        $res['quantity'], "actual" => $res['actual'], "variance" => 
        $res['variance']);
        }

        $final     = array("mawb_no" => $mawb, "status" => $stat_api, 
        "status_date" => $stat_api_date, "items" => $item_details);
```

This is the result I got:

```
     {
        "mawb_no": "MASTERPOD-1",
        "status": "Received",
        "status_date": "2019-05-27 19:35:42",
        "items": [
            {
                "sku": "RTISSUE",
                "qty": "50",
                "actual": 50,
                "variance": 0
            },
            {
                "sku": "ISOALCO",
                "qty": "102",
                "actual": 50,
                "variance": 52
            }
        ]
    }
```

What i should get:

```
    {
        "mawb_no": "MASTERPOD-1",
        "status": "Received",
        "status_date": "2019-05-27 19:35:42",
        "items": [
            {
                "sku": "RTISSUE",
                "qty": "50",
                "actual": 50,
                "variance": 0
            },
            {
                "sku": "ISOALCO",
                "qty": "102",
                "actual": 102,
                "variance": 0
            }
        ]
     }
```

Comment: feels like you should use `SUM(a.quantity) AS actual` in query. rest all seems well. Remove addition from php snippet and check.

Comment: got the same result :(

Comment: is my group by correct?

Comment: export you schema with some data if you can and send it me, it would be quicker for me like this to come up with the correct query that matches your desired results than trying to study the above relations.

Comment: @SherifSalah how do i add a zip file in comment sorry

Comment: Does your query run in SQL with correct results? Not sure if this is an CI issue, more either mapping in array construct or the SQL is not return results as expected.

Comment: @noob_girl .. send it to my email `sherifhub@gmail.com`

Comment: Hi i've sent it to your email

Comment: I dont know huhu but it's not giving me the right result :(

Comment: @noob_girl .. i got it don't worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your scheme its all working fine but with inner join it gives you all four possible results according to the conditions in you example, you need to specify exactly what is your desired result upon getting the result, you need a condition, by adding `having` condition i was able to mimic your desired results, i'm not sure that it will be valid in all cases but you can try and you got the idea anyways ( conditional inputs or conditional results ):

```
$this->db->select('d.quantity, e.sku_code, a.quantity AS actual, abs(d.quantity - a.quantity) AS variance');
$this->db->from('sk_rcv_d a');
$this->db->where('a.rcv_id', $id);
$this->db->join('sk_rcv_h b', 'a.rcv_id = b.id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('sk_booking_h c', 'b.booking_id = c.id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('sk_booking_d d', 'c.id = d.book_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('sk_item e', 'd.item_id = e.id', 'inner');
$this->db->having('actual = quantity');
```

You don't need `groub_by` in this case, and the above query will give you this:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(4) {
    ["quantity"] => string(2) "50"
    ["sku_code"] => string(7) "RTISSUE"
    ["actual"] => string(2) "50"
    ["variance"] => string(1) "0"
  }
  [1] => array(4) {
    ["quantity"] => string(3) "102"
    ["sku_code"] => string(7) "ISOALCO"
    ["actual"] => string(3) "102"
    ["variance"] => string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Comment: @noob_girl .. it took more around an hour to figure it out hahaha .. glad it worked, you are welcome any time ^-^